# Magento Performance using image Optimization tool

Tags: performance, enterprise-1.14, optimization

My current Magento EE1.14 website is loading around 9 seconds with enabling Varnish Cache, Merging JS and CSS, Having Nginx web server, enabling Zend Opcache, running page warm up scripts, enabled Magento compilation and updating Php & Mysql settings as well.

We also installed Fishpig Smush it tool for Image optimizing. the script ran almost 10hrs to optimize the images and it really optimized. When we cleared the cache, image sizes are reverted to the original version.

Fishpig Smush it tool only optimizing Media Catalog images. Is there any extension / API to optimize images in WYSIWYG folders as well

Kindly help me to find a solution to make website run under 5 secs

Comment: Time To First Byte or Full Page Loading Time? if you have varnish then your TTFB must be 400-600ms. there is something wrong with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for your comment MagenX. TTFB for my home page is aroun 1243ms(As per WebpageTest). let me know what can be best optimal setup so that i can sugges to my client.